# Primefaces - CommandButton in dialog is refreshing page

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

After click command button in a dialog, all the page is being reloaded, but I don't want to reload all page, only one component.
The dialog is show when an event of fileUpload is launched and the dialog is opened from bean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("openCropImageDialog('artistImageCropperDialog',"+this.MAX_SIZE_PX+");");
```

This is the code of the dialog component:

```
<composite:implementation>

        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="links">
            <h:panelGroup id="imageCropperDialog" layout="block" styleClass="hidden">
                <h:form id="imageCropperForm">
                    <p:imageCropper id="cropperImage" value="#{cc.attrs.croppedImage}"
                                image="/upload/#{cc.attrs.imageTmp}"
                                initialCoords="#{cc.attrs.initialCoords}"
                                aspectRatio="1"
                                minSize="#{cc.attrs.minSize}"
                                />
                    <h:commandButton id="acceptButton" action="#{cc.attrs.acceptCropAction}" styleClass="hidden">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form :messages :form:pictureHandler:updatableElements" onevent="onAcceptCropEvent"/>
                    </h:commandButton>

                    <h:commandButton id="cancelButton" action="#{cc.attrs.cancelCropAction}" styleClass="hidden">
                        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form :messages"/>
                    </h:commandButton>


                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </composite:implementation>
```

And after press Acept command button in the dialog I want to refresh only image for showing cropping image, not reloading all the page.
Can you help me to know why page is bean reloaded?

NOTE: the code in accept action:

```
public void cropImage(){
   try {
        if(croppedImage!=null){
            // Remove the old picture and add the new one
            this.entity.getPictures().clear();
            this.entity.getPictures().add(newPicture);
            this.newPictures.add(newPicture);
            int x=getOriginalSize(croppedImage.getLeft());
            int y=getOriginalSize(croppedImage.getTop());
            int width = getOriginalSize(croppedImage.getWidth());
            int height = getOriginalSize(croppedImage.getHeight());
            BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(cropInputStream);
            BufferedImage selectedImage = bImage.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
            OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(selectedImage, newPicture.getType().name().toLowerCase(), os);
            InputStream newIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream) os).toByteArray());
            int length = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) os).toByteArray().length;
            this.pictureController.createOrUpdateCompress(newPicture, newIS, length,true);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        addFacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, MessageKeys.GENERIC_ERROR_IMAGEPROCESSING,
                newPicture.getFileName(), newPicture.getType().name(), e.getMessage());
        this.newPictures.remove(newPicture);
    }
}
```

I have solved the initial problem, correcting some errors in javscript code and uncommenting ajax tags.
Now the problem is that dialog is shown only the first time, next times, dialog is not oppened. No error and no exception are shown.

Comment: Unless you've indicated differently in your web.xml, commenting out code in your xhtml has no effect, the code will still be processed. Using the `<h:commandButton/>` is what is causing the entire page to be submitted; change that to a `<p:commandButton/>`

Comment: <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: with p:commandButton it doesnt' work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check your html error log (in chrome it is available in inspect element), it seems it is generating any javascript error which is causing the button to submit whole page.

Comment: The problem for reloading form was a javascript error. But I have found another problem with fileUpload primefaces component. I'm opening a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why did you comment out ajax? Try this.

```
 <h:commandButton id="acceptButton" action="#{cc.attrs.acceptCropAction}" styleClass="hidden">
       <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":cropperImage" onevent="onAcceptCropEvent"/>

</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but page it's being reloading anyway.
I had commented ajax because page was being reloaded and I don't know why.
As the page is reloaded, I do not care to add the ajax action, since the behavior is the same.

Comment: try to add prependId to your tag <h:form id="imageCropperForm" prependId="false">

Comment: It doen't work; with this change, the command button has no effect. The page that is being reloaded is the container of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Original**

Have you tried to use the property ajax = false?

---

**Edited**

Ok, I am changing my answer here so that it can be seen clearer the work around was to simply avoid the commandButton from rendering anything but allowing the backing bean to perform the updates. There for you could do something like this

```
<h:commandButton id="acceptButton" action="#{cc.attrs.acceptCropAction}" 
styleClass="hidden" value="#{cc.attrs.acceptCropActionLabel}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
</h:commandButton>
```

then on the backing-bean you would be doing something like

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("id_of_whatever_you_want");
```

and this way it worked for me, so I hope it works for you. BTW you would need to include

```
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
```

in the backing-bean for it to work. hope it helps now.

Comment: Hmm what about trying to use a commandlink? Instead of the commandButton, or changing the type to button... I am using my mobile to answer there by not able to test, but I have done that before.. I also answer to keep track of this issue and see if I can give you a better answer.

Comment: ok, try this, `actionListener="#{cc.attrs.acceptCropAction}"`and hide the dialog on action, proceed to update the values on command, that should work otherwise, it would be necesary to see what your _acceptCropAction_ is doing in the bakcing bean.

Comment: With actionListener it doesn't work. the code of the action is detailed in original question

Comment: ok, here is the work around I implemented your code and used 

`<h:commandButton id="acceptButton" action="#{cc.attrs.acceptCropAction}" styleClass="hidden" value="#{cc.attrs.acceptCropActionLabel}" >


<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />


</h:commandButton>`
Then simply update the components you want directly from the backing bean, it worked for me, hope it does for you.

**Note:** Editing to try to make the code more readable

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved the problem, but the dialog is only shown first time, next times, the dialog is not show.

Comment: any warnings on the browser's console?

Comment: I can see that problem is caused by fileUpload primefaces component. It only works first time. Caused by this, my component with cropImage is not being shown.

Comment: by any chance do you have nested forms? I mean remember the composite you created already has a form, and if your main issue is resolved then maybe you should open another question, link it here, I would like to see it. also... try adding `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">` to the fileupload form container if you don't have it yet.